# Modifying or Adding a dicom tag

Tags: image, dictionary, tags, addition, dicom

Dealing with a few DICOM and DICONDE images(.dcm) and wanted to add new tags to those images.

I am using DICOM Browser to check the meta information of the image. It allows me to edit the value but I want to modify the tag name also, for example, from Patient ID to Component ID.

Just wondering if i have to change that in the dictionary. Where can i find the dictionary and modify it to add/edit tags.

Regards
Vish

Comment: Tags are expressed in file by a pair of (group, element). The DICOM browser has a dictionary that dispalays the tag name from this pair. It's unclear wether you want to change the display name, or the (group, element) name?

Comment: For ex: It has Tag, Name, Value.
(0010,0020), PatientID, James.  
I want to change PatientID to ComponentID. Also how can i access this dictionary?

Comment: DICOM Browser is using dcm4che, you should look into their dictionary and where they store it. Your question is very localized, I doubt you'll get answer here so search by yourself :)

Comment: But when i open the image in different dicom editors, the tags show up differently. ISee editor shows Component information instead of Patient information. So i think its how the editors name the tags. 
i want to know where to find the dictionary for any of the dicom editors..not specifically dicombrowser...Please let me know,

Comment: OK I think understood your problem, see my answer

Comment: Most tags are specified by the DICOM standard. Vendors can "invent" their own tags, but that doesn't mean that your browser knows about them. To change change PatientID to ComponentID, remove the  PatientID and add a ComponentID with the value once stored with the PatientID.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dictionary that link tags' (group, element) pairs to Tag name is not saved in the DICOM data, but defined privately by the editor/viewer, with respect to the DICOM standard.

There's no way to change it.

Comment: Oh, so its dependent on the editor. My client has sent me some dicom images, he wanted me to add a few tags which are specific to DICONDE and send back. Since i read that dicom tags can be re-used, for example, component instead of patient, i wanted to change the tag names. So basically, its the same (group, element) pair, but the  name has to change. May be its just what the sender and receiver has to agree on...

Answer (score 3):

As CharlesB points out, the tag keys carry no semantic value descriptions - they're just numbers as specified in the Dicom standard. Manufacturers often add custom fields, but since the meaning of these values is not explicit in the dicoms, they have to tell you what the values mean.  It's usually frustrating to deal with this custom data.  Please don't do this unless you have a good reason.

Comment: So if i have a DCM image with certain associated metadata, how can i add new tags to it based on the DICOM/DICONDE standard? For example, if i want to add a tag specific to "NDE CT Detector" and i have the (group,element) code with me, how can i add this to the dcm image? Is there a way to directly get all the tags of a DCM image and then add more to it, pl let me know.

Comment: There are libraries for doing this is many programming languages; are you looking for a CLI tool or a GUI or a library?  I'm partial to pydicom because I use Python a lot.

Comment: Looking for a CLI/GUI tool primarily. But can also work with a library( preferable Java). Please let me know of a CLI/GUI tool.

Comment: Have you tried a google search for 'dicom tag editor'?  I got http://nrg.wustl.edu/software/dicom-browser/ and http://dicom.dvtk.org/modules/wiwimod/index.php?page=DICOM+Editor&cmenu=products that I've never used, but are free.